# CSGO Scoped weapons

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I've been wondering for awhile now, is there a way to change the scope design on Scout and AWP? I'm not talking about changing the thickness of the scopes, but changing the default lines. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. You can change basically anything in the game by editing the files within `Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo`, but to prevent cheaters and people using unfair visuals (ex. scopes without the black on the edges) you will not be able to play on VAC-secured servers.

Comment: Or, like in the case of (the early) CS:Classic Offensive, you will get VAC-banned instantly after joining a VAC-secured server. So watch out!

Comment: @RaisingAgent in CS:GO it simply won't let you join.